# Enumerate all n-bit integers with exactly k bits set to one

Tags: c, algorithm

I am looking for a fast iterative algorithm to enumerate all n-bit integers that have exactly k bits set to one.  n can be up to 40.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Here you go: http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/?p=78

Comment: @doynax thanks.  sorry about the dupe.

Comment: The number of combinations is going to be "n choose k", unless k is small or close to n, the number integers is going to be huge. It is easy to calculate how many there will be, but enumerating them could take a while!